# How To Select DOM Element Other Than ID and Class Name

Tags: javascript, dom

Sorry if this question seems noob or doesnt make sense, i am very new to JS.

i have a web page like below -

```
<td class="main" data="chair">Chair</td>
<td class="main" data="table">Table</td>
<td class="main" data="desk">Desk</td>
```

I know how to select document by its ID or class name but here as you can see class name is same for all, how can i select value of Table?

I had tried using document.querySelectorAll and implemented foreach on it too but failed.

Can you let me know how it can be done.

Comment: Are you familiar with CSS selectors? `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` follow the same rules. Here's a list of them from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors)

Comment: Also, note that `data` isn't an attribute of a `td` element, so your HTML is invalid. You can use a `data-*` attribute instead: `data-type="chair"`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use an attribute selector:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[data="chair"]').textContent);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="main" data="chair">Chair</td>
<td class="main" data="table">Table</td>
<td class="main" data="desk">Desk</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

**Can you try this code ?**

```
function exampleTable() {
var getTables = document.querySelectorAll(".main"); 

getTables.forEach((cell) => {
    var content = cell.textContent;
    var dataAttribute = cell.getAttribute('data');

    console.log(content);
    console.log(dataAttribute);
});}
```

Comment: You are using a class name to reference main.  The question specifically asks for a method that doesn't use id or class name.